# How to hide the imageview in RecyclerView permanently through firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my first time with recyclerview and I need some help. I am using a firebase and I want to hide an item(imageview) from my recyclerview adapter.

> ```
> public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
>           super(itemView);
>           image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listrow_img1);
>           title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listrow_tv1);
>           lock = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lock_accountImg);
> }
> ```

I want to hide the lock image if my firebase realtime database don't have a child named("password"). if it has that child() the lock image will show up. Thank you in advance for those who help.

Answer (score 1):

To hide or display a view according to a condition, create a method inside the ViewHolder class:

```
public void hideDisplayImageView(boolean passwordExist) {
    if (passwordExist) {
        lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

And call from within the onBindViewHolder method:

```
String password = list.get(position).getPassword();
if(password == null) {
    holder.hideDisplayImageView(true);
} else {
   holder.hideDisplayImageView(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this  like

```
if("your condition for the child is true"){
 image.setVsisibility(View.VISIBLE)}
 else{
 image.setVsisibility(View.GONE)}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Kolin

```
val firebaseData = list.[position].getChild()
if(!firebaseData == "password")
  holder.image.isVisible = false
else holder.image.isVisible = true
```

> Java

```
String firebaseData = list.getPosition().getChild();
if(!firebaseData.contains("password")){
   holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE)
  }else{
     holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) 
  }
```